# Java Threads: synchronized reading and writing of value on the same object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am a bit confused about this task I have about threads: I have three classes:

- a class that stores an integer, let's call it `StoredInteger`
- a Thread class (`IncrementThread`) that is supposed to increment the integer value of the `StoredInteger` class
- another thread class (`ReadThread`) that is supposed to read the integer value from the `StredInteger` class

The process should go in the way that the output should be synchronized, for example:

- `IncementThread` writes the value 1 to the `StoredInteger`
- `ReadThread` reads value 1 from `StoredInteger`
- `IncementThread` writes the value 2 to the `StoredInteger`
- `ReadThread` reads value 2 from `StoredInteger`
  ...and so on

The issue I have is that the ReadThread waits for the IncrementThread to finish and then it only reads the last value. Here's some of my code:

```
public class ReadThread extends Thread {

    private StoredInteger stored_integer;
    ...

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 100)
        {
            synchronized(this.getStoredInteger())
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ...
                }
                System.out.format("%s: Reading %d from StoredInteger\n", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), this.getStoredInteger().getValue());
                i++;
            }

        }
    }

   ...
}
```

.

```
public class IncrementThread extends Thread {

private StoredInteger stored_integer;

    ...

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(i < 100)
        {
            synchronized(this.getStoredInteger())
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                   ...
                }
                System.out.format("%s: Writing %d to StoredInteger\n", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), i);
                this.getStoredInteger().setValue(i);
                i++;
            }          
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And the threads running:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        StoredInteger intgr = new StoredInteger();
        Thread write = new Thread(new IncrementThread(intgr));
        Thread read = new Thread(new ReadThread(intgr));
        write.start();
        read.start();
        write.join();
        read.join();

    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in your code guarantees that the read/write threads work alternately. You basically have both threads entering a mutual exclusion zone. They wait there for 1second (keeping the locks) and write or read a value. You could have the sleep outside the mutex zone, but again, it wouldn't guarantee that the threads would work alternately (although with 1sec of sleep() it would be almost certain they would).

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        synchronized (stored_integer) {
            System.out.format("%s: Writing %d to StoredInteger\n", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), i);
            stored_integer.value = i;
            i++;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        synchronized (stored_integer) {
            System.out.format("%s: Reading %d from StoredInteger\n", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), stored_integer.value);
            i++;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

However, to do it properly, you need to use the wait() and notify() methods. Have the writer thread wait after it writes, so the reader thread can read and wake up the writer. Something like this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        synchronized (stored_integer) {
            System.out.format("%s: Writing %d to StoredInteger\n", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), i);
            stored_integer.value = i;
            i++;

            // Writer wakes up writer
            stored_integer.notify();

            // Writer waits until it can read
            try {
                stored_integer.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                //
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    synchronized (stored_integer) {
        // Reader waits for the first time!
        try {
            stored_integer.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            //
        }
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100) {
        synchronized (stored_integer) {

            System.out.format("%s: Reading %d from StoredInteger\n", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), stored_integer.value);
            i++;

            // Reader wakes up writer
            stored_integer.notify();

            // If there are still more values to read
            if (i < 100) {
                // Reader waits until it can read
                try {
                    stored_integer.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On your main, use start() first on the reader thread and only then on the writer thread. Even then, there might be a chance for the code not to work. If your processor should not do the wait from the Reader before the Notify() from the writer (which could happen, because these are threads, afterall), you would go into deadlock. A way to solve it would be having a condition variable where it would wait (if needed) and only start the writer thread after the reader were blocked waiting for it.

Comment: That was the issue! Thank you for your effort :)

Comment: More easily with 2 semaphores

Comment: Indeed! I'm just more used to monitors :P

Answer (score 1):

You might want to move the sleep call out of the synchronized block, otherwise  it still maintains the lock on the variable while it is sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting thread.sleep after synchronized block

Answer (score 1):

How about ReentrantReadWriteLock?
See java.util.concurrent.locks.

Comment: ReentrantLock seem to be a more efficient solution that offers the guarantee on the order threads are executed. The solution suggested by the above answers do the job (I've got to recognize that I needed to make a small wait time adjustment to keep the order). For now, the suggested solution solves my task, but I can give you a plus for your suggestion and I will definitely use it in the future. Thanks!