# How to use synchronized block in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to use synchronized block for my use-case where I need to use it on following code.

```
public void saveInCatch(String reqId,String desc) {
    synchronized (reqId) {
        cache.add(reqId,desc);
    }
}
```

This method is getting called from many places in my application. I want to make sure that the code block should be accessed by only one thread at a time if the `reqId` is same. If it is different then this block can be accessed concurrently. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I want to make sure that the code block should be accessed by only one thread at a time if the reqId is same. If it is different then this block can be accessed concurrently.

Comment: _if the `reqId` is same_ Same as what? How do you check whether the `reqId` is the same?

Comment: i.e. if one thread have same reqId as that of other thread.

Comment: i wouldn't recommend re-inventing the wheel here. there are lots of open source libraries with caches already existing (from simple to complex).  or, just use ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 2):

So the problem here is ensuring that two or more threads that synchronize on the same request id get mutual exclusion for this block of code.

People might think the code already does that, but it doesn't.  The issue is that two `String` objects may be equal according to `Object.equal(Object)` without being the same object ... according to `==`.  If different threads threads lock on different copies of the same request id, your code won't give you mutual exclusion based on request id values.

... which you probably realized ... and that is the reason you asked this question!

---

One solution is to simply `intern` the request ids; e.g.

```
public void saveInCatch(String reqId, String desc) {
    synchronized (reqId.intern()) {
        cache.add(reqId, desc);
    }
}
```

Interning gives you a "canonical" version of the request string.  By locking on the canonical string, you guarantee to get mutual exclusion on the request id.

There are a couple of downsides with this approach:

1. If you do this a lot, you are liable to fill the JVM's string pool:

   - Prior to Java 7, this could lead to permgen exhaustion in the worst case, or a lot of "full" garbage collections.
   - In Java 7, the string pool was moved to the regular heap, and interned strings that are no longer reachable will be collected.  However, there are still considerable memory and garbage collection overheads associated with interned strings.
2. If two sections of your application are doing this kind of thing for different purposes, you could potentially get lock interference between locks for different classes of resources.

---

A second approach is to use lock striping.  You could implement this by hand (as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71512849/139985) by @pveentjer), or you could use the Guava `Striped` class ([javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/24.0-android/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Striped.html)); e.g.

```
private static final Striped<Lock> locks = Striped.lock(nosStripes);

...

public void saveInCatch(String reqId, String desc) {
    Lock lock = locks.get(reqId);
    try {
        lock.lock();
        cache.add(reqId, desc);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The downside of lock striping is that you are *more likely* to get lock interference, due to different request ids mapping to the same lock.  But the upside is that the memory and GC overheads are bounded by the (constant) number of stripes you use.

---

Finally, as noted by @jtahlborn, you are probably reinventing the wheel.  There are existing open source concurrent cache classes that you could use, or you could use `ConcurrentHashMap` with some kind of cleaner.

Comment: There’s a fundamental logic error. Either, `cache` is thread safe, then this entire locking (regardless of which approach) is obsolete, or it is not, in which case the code is broken as using different locks or synchronization objects does not form a thread safe access to the `cache`. I can’t imagine any scenario where this approach is useful. A `ConcurrentHashMap` does the job, except that it’s not locking at all for such a trivial `put`. It’s not clear why you’re suggesting a cleaner. It seems you’re thinking ahead, to a use case the OP didn’t explain.

Comment: Yes ... I am thinking ahead.  A third party cache implementation will most likely have a build in mechanism to prevent it being a memory leak.  A `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't do that.  You need to implement your own scheme for cleaning out the old entries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `synchronized(Object)` expects a *unique* Object.

However the following two reqIds are not identical.

```
String reqId = Integer.toString(42);
...
String reqId = Integer.toString(6*7);
```

One heavily costing simple solution would be:

```
synchronized(reqId.intern()) {
```

Instead make the Map of your `cache` a `ConcurrentHashMap` or its Navigable version.

```
Cache cache = new Cache();

class Cache {
    ConcurrentMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    void add(String key, String value) {
        map.merge(...);
    }
}

public void saveInCatch(String reqId, String desc) {
    cache.add(reqId, desc);
}
```

By using `merge` you may keep changes inside the concurrent put.

Should there be done *several* state changes besides adding to the map,
you could do that by `synchronized` on the inner key of the map.

Mind, I do not like this solution, as it is brittle, and hard to test.

Probably concurrent queues for atomic actions can be more solid. We are probably now looking at just one facet of data.

Answer (score 0):

Having a single lock would be one option, but would allow for only 1 concurrent request.

A different approach is to use a striped lock. So you create an array objects, and based on the hash of the string, you determine the index of object in the striped lock.

So you get something like this:

```
synchronized(stripedLock[toIndex(key)]){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are looking when one thread is wiritting still another thread should be able to read it

I think that would be tricky to do. Since the value should be flushed out to memory.

Check the link for similar question

[Java Threads: synchronized reading and writing of value on the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520129/java-threads-synchronized-reading-and-writing-of-value-on-the-same-object)

Comment: I have updated my question.please check. Basically diffrent threads will save their data in a cache. And different thread might have same reqId.

Comment: Flushing to memory is a fallacy. https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/close-encounters-of-jmm-kind/#myth-commit-semantics

Answer (score -1):

The synchronized block works on the instance Id of the object you are matching

so with your code I can create two strings

```
String id1 = "1234";
String id2 = "1234";
```

If two threads call your function using different variables containing the same Id then they will not get blocked, they will both run.

If you really want to sychronize on a string like that you should create static final String objects for every possible Id

Note: if you decide to use a numeric type like Integer for you sync object then you might find it works for low numbers and then stops working as numbers get higher as Java uses a table of Ints so that only one version of 1 will be created for your code, but every instance of 9999 might have a unique object Id

Comment: Re, "using different variables," The two variables in your example both will refer to the same string _instance._ What matters in a `synchronized(foo)` statement is the identity of the instance to which `foo` refers. In fact, you don't need to use a variable at all: This might be a bit of an anti-pattern, but it would be perfectly legal to write `synchronized(myObject.getLock()){...}`.

Comment: Re, "you should create `static final String` objects..." `final` is good practice. `static` is not. The _extent_ (i.e., the lifetime) of the lock object should be the same as the extent of the data that it protects. It is very common to want to protect the _fields_ of some class, in which case, in which case, the best practice would be to use a `final`, but _not_ `static` field to hold the lock object, and create a new, distinct lock object for each instance of the class. Only make a lock `static` if the data it protects are static.

Comment: Re, "If you really want to synchronizes on a `String`," or "if you decide to use a numeric type like `Integer` for you sync object." Just _don't._ It's a Bad Idea. Even if you know what you're doing and you can make it work, you're making extra work for any other programmer who reads your code. As soon as they see you synchronizing on a `String` or on an `Integer`, then they will be like, "What the ****!" and they will have to study your code to figure out whether it really works or not, assuming they even want to read it at all after seeing that ****!

Answer (score -2):

If you understand synchronization correctly it will lock the method and object until it is done being use by one thread but you sometimes also want `reqId` to be access concurrently. You can use `volatile` keyword in the variable though like `private volatile String reqId;`(Make the `reqId` an instance variable). According to the book:

**volatile-This keyword indicates to the VM that
the value may be changed by external threads and effectively synchronizes access to it
automatically.**